# In Tensorflow, why is print() executed in both statements of an if-else?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code, I make a function whose arguments are two tensors and an array of indices (related to the last axis of the tensors). The function will go through the last axis of the tensors, extract a slice of the tensor, do some operations (not included here), and finally build a new tensor. The input indices just indicate which tensor should be treated each time. Very simple!

The code works well. However, I noticed that if I place a print() in both statements of the if-else, it is always executed, whereas I can see in the output that only the correct statement was performed. Why is that?

```py
@tf.function
def build_mixed_tensor(x, x2, ixCh):
    # Make a boolean mask for the channels axis (True if channel selected)
    mask = tf.equal(tf.range(0,x.shape[-1]), tf.expand_dims(ixCh, 1))
    mask = tf.reduce_any(mask, axis=0)

    # Deal with the channels
    for ii in range(0, x.shape[-1]):
      if mask[ii]:
        print('This is for True')
        selChn = tf.gather(x, [ii], axis=-1)
        # Do some operations ...
        print(selChn.shape)
      else:
        print('This is for False')
        selChn = tf.gather(x2, [ii], axis=-1)
        # Do some operations ...
        print(selChn.shape)

      if ii == 0:
        outChn = selChn
      else:
        outChn = tf.concat([outChn, selChn], axis=2)
      print(outChn.shape)
    return outChn

# Create two tensors
inp1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(3 * 4 * 5, dtype=tf.int32), [3, 4, 5])
inp2 = tf.reshape(tf.range(100, 100+(3 * 4 * 5), dtype=tf.int32), [3, 4, 5])
updated = build_mixed_tensor(inp1, inp2, [1,2])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('This is the mixed tensor:')
    print(sess.run(updated))
```

The output is:

```
This is for True
(3, 4, 1)
This is for False
(3, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 1)
This is for True
(3, 4, 1)
This is for False
(3, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 2)
This is for True
(3, 4, 1)
This is for False
(3, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 3)
This is for True
(3, 4, 1)
This is for False
(3, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 4)
This is for True
(3, 4, 1)
This is for False
(3, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 5)
This is the mixed tensor:
[[[100   1   2 103 104]
  [105   6   7 108 109]
  [110  11  12 113 114]
  [115  16  17 118 119]]

 [[120  21  22 123 124]
  [125  26  27 128 129]
  [130  31  32 133 134]
  [135  36  37 138 139]]

 [[140  41  42 143 144]
  [145  46  47 148 149]
  [150  51  52 153 154]
  [155  56  57 158 159]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question! This is because the first time a function with the `@tf.function` decorator is called, the function is *traced* so that later only the traced graph needs to be executed (which is usually faster). However, this means that *both* branches are traced so that the correct one can be chosen immediately at runtime.

This only happens when the condition is on a `Tensor` (which it is in your case). If it was a "regular" Python bool, only the branch with the true condition would be traced, but this doesn't really apply to your example because the bool depends on a tensor, so it will be a tensor as well anyway.

I highly recommend looking at [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#using_autograph) on the official TF website, which describes this as well as some other peculiarities.